# Cannot authenticate in app using vite network

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, vite, mern

I m working on a real time chat app build with MERN Stack . I m using vite to set up my react front-end. As this is a real time chat application i want to see or open it in two devices simultaneously to show real time data / messages transfer. For this i m using **vite --host** networks so that along with the host device i can open that project in other device as well for e.g other pc or my mobile phone.

```
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.56.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.0.104:5173/
```

The project is opening in other device using the network links of vite. The only problem is that i m not able to authenticate in the app *i.e* **login** or **register** on the other device (my mobile phone.)
It should not happen like that. Whenever i try to login or register .... it just stuck and the request doesn't gets completed .
I m using **cors** package in **nodejs** to it be accessed from anywhere on network.
Although i have given network access from all ips in the mongodb database for this project. 0.0.0.0/0

This is my socket connection to frontend:

```
const io = new Server({
    cors: 'http://192.168.0.104:5173',
});
```

I have used my host pc's ipv4 instead of localhost as i want to connect from other device as well using that ip

This is how i m initializing my socket on the front end :

```
   // Initialize Socket
    useEffect(() => {
        const newSocket = io('http://192.168.0.104:5000');
        setSocket(newSocket);
        return () => {
            newSocket.disconnect();
        };
    }, [user]);
```

Need some help as to where m i going wrong.